# A dramedy, a sitcom, satire TV series?

Tags: word-request

My friends and I, who are Upper Intermediate English Learners, had a discussion about the type of a [local TV series](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt5477572/) which is comedy and each episode lasts for almost an hour. IMDB suggests comedy as the genre although it's too general and it's not what I'm looking for.

I suggested [*sitcom*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitcom) since it's comedy and the show features same characters. However, as my friend said sitcoms are mostly half an hour long or less with laugh tracks included and they don't follow the same story all along, so he proposed a [*satire TV series*](https://www.reference.com/art-literature/satire-comedy-bcfb75bf19057708) since it criticizes doctors' bedside manner and the problems that patients have to deal with about unnecessary paperwork. I said in response sitcoms can include satire too and there are alot of scenes in the local series that is just included to make audience laugh without any satirical purpose like a [slapstick scene](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slapstick).

[Dramedy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedy-drama) is another option that we came up with since some episodes not all there are some short scenes that the character are sad and the show tries to make a point about life although I argued [Friends](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends) is also comedy and includes these scenes but it's still a sitcom.

I read all the links included here and some more but I couldn't get a definite answer to that. I wonder what's the right English word to describe this TV show which 1) is an hour long; 2) includes satire; 3) follows a story; 4) features same characters; 5) doesn't use laugh tracks.

Comment: I wouldn't focus on the length of the program for any classification other than the time allowed to develop the story line. A series (same characters, settings and basic plot) are usually a drama or if comedic a sitcom. It would be a satire or slapstick only if that were the primary style of the program. Have never heard "dramedy" before. However I think this is more of an entertainment question, since you are asking about performance style and not the meaning of words.

Comment: Honestly it sounds like you're already pretty familiar with the entertainment lingo, so there's not a lot a native speaker could add.  Certainly sitcoms are usually satire, so it doesn't have to be one or the other.  *Friends* is a sitcom, but the classic "dramedy" is *M.A.S.H.*, in that most episodes included both comedic and dramatic elements.   If your show is like *M.A.S.H.* then "dramedy" works.  If it's more about humor, then it's a sitcom.  Either way, you can have fun arguing about it.  :)

Comment: I can't for the life of me understand how this question is a about learning the English language, but it seems to me that the American series _House_ is a possible model for labelling this program. IMDB calls that "drama, mystery." When I watched it, it seemed a comedy at times. What do the Mullahs call it? Isn't that more important than how it might be described in English?

Comment: Thank you all. The problem is I haven't watched M.A.S.H so I was unfamiliar with comedy-drama I just have seen a couple of American sitcoms like Friends, or How I Met your Mother. So it was tricky to understand the concept. Well I like searching and spent an hour reading about all these lingos but it wasn't easy to label :( . I needed some insight for the word choice or even a new word.

Comment: @P. E. Dant if that's supposed to be funny I don't get it. If that's racist or something, I don't care :) so which one?

Comment: Good gracious, I have no idea what racist could mean there! I meant that there are religious authorities in some places who have political power and who have their _own_ ways of categorizing media, and of declaring this or that entertainment permissible, or preventing it from being seen. Isn't that so?

Comment: @P. E. Dant Oh then that was _or something_ part. Yea, unfortunately there are sometimes unfavourable authorities, but you know usually it's not their job to start labeling TV series! There are redlines concerning what to be included in TV productions and they're mainly about criticizing the most important official positions which are one or two but social issues and services are OK to be lashed out by media. Sorry for my previous comment. For a moment I thought you might be a _lame comedian_ or a _Nazi s**t_ but you're better than that :)

Comment: @Yuri I have nothing but sympathy for anyone who has to put up with being told by some self-appointed "guardian" what they can wear, or say, or believe, or watch on TV. We are very fortunate in "the West" to have no such worries.

Comment: @P. E. Dant yes indeed. Things suddenly went south for us 40 years ago. Thanks, you're a good lad.

Comment: @Yuri Have faith, my friend, and don't give up the fight. Eventually the old farts die, and humans always find a way to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no limit on the length of an episodes of a sit-com, nor any requirement for a laugh track. A simple sequence of jokes would be hard to sustain for an hour, so longer sit-coms tend to have more elements of drama: For example *Ally McBeal*, *Northern Exposure* or *Moonlighting* are tv shows with a mixture of comedy, tragedy and romance. Forums: [Snopes](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-119195.html) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/comments/2uvuuc/eli5_why_are_tv_sitcoms_always_30_minutes_long/) have discussed this.

I'd go for a sit-com, or a "[comedy drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comedy-drama)", just because I dislike the look of dramedy.